# Open source solutions for Landsat-8 mosaicing and correction?

Tags: remote-sensing, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, landsat, mosaic

I am familiar with the major commercial remote sensing packages (ENVI, IDRISI ERDAS, etc), but I haven't previously had the opportunity to utilize open-source solutions.

I have a several new Landsat-8 images that I would like to mosaic for both simple display and analysis (land cover classification). Is there a go-to open source software for this, or are there many options? A tutorial would also be excellent.

Comment: Mapbox imagery specialist Charlie Loyd wrote a [great article](http://www.mapbox.com/blog/processing-landsat-8/) for their blog about processing Landsat 8 using only Open Source tools.  He added the image to tilemill which you could conceivably use as a basis for mosaicing the scenes together.

Comment: Good article on getting started - I'm unfamiliar with tilemill, but it looks to be used for creating web maps. Is there something similar that can be used to create maps for classification purposes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may consider GRASS GIS which offers a rather complete processing chain for Landsat including radiance correction for Landsat 8. For details, see

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LANDSAT

Examples:

- Landsat 1-5,7,8 data import
- Auto-enhance colors, natural color composites
- Calculate Top-of-Atmosphere Reflectance and band-6 Temperature
- Haze removal
- Atmospheric correction
- Cloud identification
- image classification
- time series analysis
- Export of results

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Landsat-util](https://github.com/developmentseed/landsat-util) repository

You should also consider using Landsat data from AWS. You can get a good overview of different usages to process Landsat data on [this Amazon AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/start-using-landsat-on-aws/)

For Landsat data downloading, go to [LANDSAT-Download](https://github.com/olivierhagolle/LANDSAT-Download) repository