# Atmospheric Corrections for Landsat 8 OLI Using Orfeo Toolbox

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, sextante, landsat, orfeo-toolbox

I am trying to correct some Landsat 8 OLI imagery using the Orfeo Toolbox Optical Calibration tool via QGIS.  I've retrieved data from Aeronet as well as relative spectral response data for the OLI sensor from [here.](http://landsat.usgs.gov/tools_spectralViewer.php)  However, I can't seem to get the tool to run.  I'm having difficulty finding any documentation beyond that I need the RSR file and the Aeronet file.  What I'm unsure of is A: what format the relative spectral response data needs to be in, and B: what file counts as the Aeronet file?  Aeronet gives me several datasets to choose from here.  Alternatively, if anyone has any suggestions for alternative methods or tools, I'll gladly hear them.

Comment: What is AERONET? Did you get the Landsat files from USGS?  What is your intended output, radiance reflectance, surface top of atmosphere?

Comment: Aeronet is http://aeronet.gsfc.nasa.gov/
Beyond that, all I know is they collect information on Aerosols and that the OTB tool asks for it.  I did download the level 1 multispectral product directly from USGS, and I'm hoping to get corrected surface reflectance at the end of this.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using GRASS (which interfaces with QGIS) for this process. See this link for more information: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LANDSAT

The [answer provided by @markusN on this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67657/open-source-solutions-for-landsat-8-mosaicing-and-correction) provides additional information and examples of what GRASS can be used for with Landsat-8.